# react-native run-ios fails at Copying w/ error: <mypath> No such file or directory

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

When I run `react-native run-ios` from the command line my build fails at the `Copying` stage with error;

```
error: /Users/Brad/Documents/reefbuddy/ios/ios: No such file or directory
```

My project directory structure;

```
- reefbuddy   
  - ios
    - build
      - Build
        - Products
          reefbuddy.app
  -reefbuddy
    AppDelegate.h
    Appdelegate.m
  reefbuddy.xcodeproj
  reefbuddy.xcworkspace
```

Screenshot of complete terminal output;
[image: terminal error message]

React Native Environment Info:

```
System:
  OS: macOS 10.14
  CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3667U CPU @ 2.00GHz
  Memory: 243.36 MB / 8.00 GB
  Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node: 8.11.2 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
  npm: 6.7.0 - ~/.npm-packages/bin/npm
  Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
  iOS SDK:
    Platforms: iOS 12.1, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1
  Android SDK:
    API Levels: 25
IDEs:
  Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4720617
  Xcode: 10.1/10B61 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
  react: 16.6.3 => 16.6.3 
  react-native: 0.58.5 => 0.58.5 
npmGlobalPackages:
  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
  react-native-git-upgrade: 0.2.7
```

It seems the `ios/ios` portion of the path is wrong but I don't know if that is true or how to change it.

Building from Xcode as suggested fails with the following error;
[image]

Same as the error reported at [Xcode corrupts project.pbxproj everytime I try to build with Xcode post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54645609/xcode-corrupts-project-pbxproj-everytime-i-try-to-build-with-xcode)

Comment: The console error is hinting that it can't find CFBundleIdentifier in your Info.plist.  Since you can set Info.plist in both RN and Xcode, building the app with Xcode sometimes syncs it up for you.

Comment: @stever I tried as you suggested but running `react-native run-ios` still produces the same error. I added the additional error that Xcode produced trying to do the build there. I think the missing CFBundleIdentifier may be a seperate or symptomatic issue from the failure of the `CpResource` command as shown in the error screenshot from running `react-native run-ios`.

Comment: @BradW Did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the path of the target "absolute" instead of "relative" in Xcode will fix it.